# Move library from global site package to virtual environment in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

Normally, when I start a new project I ensure to select "Inherit global site-packages" when creating the new environment.

This time I forgot.

Is there a way to move the pre-existing packages from my machine into the virtual environment? This would save me time `pip`ing all the stuff I need all over again.

I realize this is not necessarily sound practice, but I'm just a student teaching myself this stuff at home. I do not need to keep my dependencies separate at this point.

Comment: Why is not re-creating venv an option?

Comment: @user2235698 Mostly because I don't know how :) I see no option to "recreate". I do see add a new environment, but it does not work ("Environment location directory is not empty"). I can delete the venv folder, but I'm not sure if that's a good idea or not. Hence, the question :)

Comment: Yep, it's ok to remove virtual environment folder and re-create it in the same location. Please don't forget to remove it from PyCharm settings as well (`File - Settings - Project - Project Interpreter - <ComboBox> - Show All`)